# How to select prompts on a dropdown menu using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait, selenium-webdriver-python

My goal is to search for an item on the microcenter store. However, I need to select a store to choose in a dropdown menu so that I can get the proper search results. I cannot figure out how to do this. For some reason driver.find_elements_by_class_name does not work to open up the dropdown.

Here is my code:

```
#selenium imports
from re import search
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)/chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
what_search = "card"
driver.get("https://www.microcenter.com/search/search_results.aspx?N=4294966998&NTX=mode+MatchPartial&NTT=rtx+graphics+cards&NTK=all&page=1&cat=Computer-Parts-:-MicroCenter")
#searches for what_search
print(driver.title)
search = driver.find_element_by_name("Ntt")

search.send_keys(what_search)
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
#this opens up the dropdown menu
store = driver.find_element_by_id("Change-Store")
store.click()
time.sleep(1)


#these are my "attempts" to open up and click on a store location option

#storeclick = driver.find_element_by_class_name("btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle selectorHref")
#storeclick = driver.find_element_by_class_name("dropdown-item")
storeclick = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("dropdown-itemLI store_055")
print(storeclick)
storeclick.click()
print("I TRIED")
```

The main issue is:

```
storeclick = driver.find_element_by_class_name("btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle selectorHref")
```

does not work to find the dropdown menu button

```
<li class="dropdown-itemLI store_055"><a class="dropdown-item" href="/search/search_results.aspx?N=4294966998&amp;NTX=mode+MatchPartial&amp;NTT=rtx+graphics+cards&amp;NTK=all&amp;page=1&amp;cat=Computer-Parts-%3a-MicroCenter&amp;storeid=055">MI - Madison Heights</a></li>
```

Thus I cannot click on it.

I want to click on the dropdown menu, then select a store option:

[image: I want to click on the dropdown menu, then select a store option]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using only class name can be tricky to find if the webpage is too big. Try using xpath instead so you can use more filters. Here is an example that can find the button:

Element:
`<li class="dropdown-itemLI store_055"><a class="dropdown-item" href="/search/search_results.aspx?N=4294966998&amp;NTX=mode+MatchPartial&amp;NTT=rtx+graphics+cards&amp;NTK=all&amp;page=1&amp;cat=Computer-Parts-%3a-MicroCenter&amp;storeid=055">MI - Madison Heights</a></li>`

Xpath: `//li[@class="dropdown-itemLI store_055"]//a[@class="dropdown-item"]`

```
storeclick = drive.find_elements_by_xpath('//li[@class="dropdown-itemLI store_055"]//a[@class="dropdown-item"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

To click on the element with text as ***MI - Madison Heights*** you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Code Block:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.microcenter.com/search/search_results.aspx?N=4294966998&NTX=mode+MatchPartial&NTT=rtx+graphics+cards&NTK=all&page=1&cat=Computer-Parts-:-MicroCenter")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.btn.btn-light.accept"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "MI - Madison Heights"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: microcenter]